# "Adaption" vs "adaptation"

Tags: meaning, differences

I'm writing a formal paper and have a section about the process of adapting a model to a new situation.

Should I title the section *model adaption* or *model adaptation*?

I'm rather confused by the difference between the two words. I am inclined to use *adaption* but I don't know why.

Comment: Pretty much any dictionary will tell you that *adaption* is just a variant of *adaptation*. Only use *adaption* if it's a term of art in your particular field.

Comment: @JSBangs: Few dictionaries will clarify that *adaption is just a variant of adaptation* as opposed to *adaptation is just a variant of adaption*. None of mine, certainly. You need to know something of existing usage to decide which is the "base" form (if that even means anything).

Comment: Hello and welcome to EL&U, GreyCloud! [No need to sign your posts](http://english.stackexchange.com/faq#signatures) — your user name serves as signature enough, and it links to your profile, where you can add anything else you'd like us to know :)

Answer (score 10):

[The FreeDictionary.com](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/adaption) doesn't believe there is a difference between the two. In formal writing, I would prefer "adaptation" (which I can find in the OED) to what looks like a spelling mistake that has been transmuted into a word. More to the point "adaptation" is a variant of adapt that follows the same pattern as, e.g., "expectation" and "expect".

Answer (score 5):

The *Shorter* OED doesn't give **adaption**, as @ig0774 says. It'll be in the *Complete*, though, because it's definitely a valid word. But I certainly agree with others, **adaptation** is to be preferred.

Exactly the same has happened with **adoption** and **adoptation**, except in that case the shorter word became the standard form.

So far as I'm concerned these are (rare) examples of true synonyms. Unsurprising, maybe, since they use very similar (and both legitimate) ways of deriving a noun from a verb. But if we're to consider the smallest of details, it's fair to say that in each case, the less-common form has overtones of long-winded verbosity.

Comment: I should clarify that I was simply looking at the Shorter OED (not the full version), which does miss a surprising number of words.

Comment: @ig0774: oic. Well, I expect the Shorter probably doesn't give *adoptation* either. They're definitely both valid words, but not common enough to be put in dictionaries that are trying to keep the size down.

Comment: It wasn't really my intention to imply that adaption wasn't a word, though I realize though that my answer sort of implied that. I just meant to point out that adaptation is likely the more common variant. The bit about the "spelling mistake" (which is a gratuitous assumption) was more to do with Latin. Adapt comes from adaptare, which would give adaptat- as the root of it's variant forms. However, adaptare is itself a combination of ad + aptus, which may well be the source of the variation.

Comment: @ig0774: Well I always stand to be corrected, but I'd have thought by that logic **adaptative** ought to be more common than **adaptive**, which it clearly isn't (though again, my *Chambers* is happy they are both valid words).

Comment: I'm not really sure that follows. **Adaptive** seems like it's just the adjectival form of the noun **adapt**. The suffix **-tion** in this case, as with **expectation** indicates a noun derived from a verb form. Etymology, though, is no predictor of common usage. I suppose that makes my whole point kind of moot.

Comment: +1 on the comment for excellent usage of the word "moot". Which frankly I think the whole question is. I wouldn't have Answered at all except it gave me a chance to flag up the opposite process with "adopt". And I really *do* feel those two different processes have influenced each other in terms of encouraging a more noticeable distinction between the derived forms.

Answer (score 0):

I think adaptation sounds more appropriate, and is probably used more often than adaption. This might just be my personal preference though, so take it for that.